# Prevent combobox from changing the selected option when user types. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox which has focus, if the user types a character, how do I prevent the combobox to change the selected index.

Say I have a combobox with options "A" and "B", "A" is selected and the combobox has focus, if the user presses "B", the combobox changes to the "B" option, how do I prevent this from happening?

The reason I want to do this is because I'm using a barcode scanner and the dropdown contains a list of printers, the selected printer prints something related to what the barcode scanner scans. So If I the combobox/dropdown has focus and the barcode scanner sends input, it changes the selected printer.

This is the first solution I used: I used the keypress event on the combobox and set the handled flag to true

```
    private void comboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But this solution does not work for Windows 98.

Comment: Change DropDownStyle = DropDownList it will become Readonly .

Comment: TaZz, the DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList. The text in the combobox is not editable, but when you type a char the combobox jumps to the option that begins with that char(if such an option exists)

Comment: @TaZz DropDownList will still select from the list on keypress, if it finds a match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the originally selected value and then replace it when you're handling the KeyPress.

I would much recommend setting the focus to the control before you set the value, or disabling the combo box for the duration of the barcode scanning.

Comment: This is what I eventually used: http://pastie.org/private/eh01lrhfe4yadikzuwsutw I store the selected index on keydown and set it back it on keyup. I would have rather disabled the combobox during the scan but in my application it's rather tricky to determine when I get input from the barcode scanner so I settled for the solution I mentioned.